# Regex Javascript add space after punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I'm using `replace(/\s*([,.!?:;])[,.!?:;]*\s*/g, '$1 ')` to add space after punctuation. But it doesn't work if the sentence contains three dots.

Example text: "Hello,today is a beautiful day...But tomorrow is,not."

Expected output: "Hello, today is a beautiful day... But tomorrow is, not."

```
let text = "Hello,today is a beautiful day...But tomorrow is,not.";
text = text.replace(/\s*([,.!?:;])[,.!?:;]*\s*/g, '$1 ')
```

Gives:
"Hello, today is a beautiful day. But tomorrow is, not. "

Please tell me what regex I can use so that I can get the expected output.

Comment: Why do you remove all consecutive punctuation but the first one? Try just `/\s*([,.!?:;]+)\s*/g`. See https://regex101.com/r/mKgPFG/1

Comment: Do you want to catch the last (sequence) of punctuation too? This would add a space at the end of a line. Maybe use some trim function right after, or add to the pattern itself.

Comment: Yeah, adding that condition to the above regex is simple: `/\s*([,.!?:;]+)(?!\s*$)\s*/g`. Please explain your regex requirements in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  should match all consecutive punctuation chars into Group 1, not just the first char. Also, it makes sense to exclude a match of the punctuation at the end of the string.

You can use

```js
text.replace(/\s*([,.!?:;]+)(?!\s*$)\s*/g, '$1 ')
```

Also, it still might be handy to `.trim()` the result. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKgPFG/2).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitspace chars
- `([,.!?:;]+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more `,`, `.`, `!`, `?`, `:` or `;`
- `(?!\s*$)` - if not immediately followed with zero or more whitespace chars and then end of string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitspace chars

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
let text = "Hello,today is a beautiful day...But tomorrow is,not.";
text = text.replace(/\s*([,.!?:;]+)(?!\s*$)\s*/g, '$1 ');
console.log(text);
```

Comment: How to improve this approach to avoid adding space with number like `1.200 1,200`?

Comment: @TuanvanDuong `/\s*(?<!\d(?=[,.]\d))([,.!?:;]+)(?!\s*$)\s*/g`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew
 I got error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name` with this regex: `text = text.replace(/\s*(?<!\d(?=[,.]\d))([,.!?:;]+)(?!\s*$)\s*/g, '$1 ');`

Comment: @TuanvanDuong You are using an outdated JS engine. So, you can only use `text.replace(/\s*(?:\d[,.]\d|([,.!?:;]+))(?!\s*$)\s*/g, function(m, x) { return x ? x+' ' : m;})`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Great, it works now. Thank you so much. Just found 2 minor issues is that if the `...` at the end, then it adds space after the second `.`. And if the `.` inside a quote, then it still adds space after `.`. For ex, if the text is `I said "Today is a beatiful day.". But tomorrow will be a long day...` becomes `I said "Today is a beatiful day. ". But tomorrow will be a long day.. .`. Any idea?

Comment: @TuanvanDuong Something like `replace(/\.{3,}|\s*(?=([,.!?:;]+))\1(?!\s*$)(?!")\s*/g, function(m, x) { return x ? x+' ' : m;})` can help.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks for your suggestion. I combined your previous regex with this one and come up with the one which works for me: `replace(/\.{3,}$|\s*(?:\d[,.]\d|([,.!?:;]+))(?!\s*$)(?!")\s*/g, (m0, m1) => { return m1 ? m1 + ' ' : m0; });`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew for his suggestions and I come up with the final regex that meets my requirements:

```js
let text = 'Test punctuation:c,c2,c3,d1.D2.D3.Q?.Ec!Sc;Test number:1.200 1,200 2.3.Test:money: $15,000.Test double quote and three dots:I said "Today is a...beautiful,sunny day.".But tomorrow will be a long day...';
text = text.replace(/\.{3,}$|\s*(?:\d[,.]\d|([,.!?:;]+))(?!\s*$)(?!")\s*/g, (m0, m1) => { return m1 ? m1 + ' ' : m0;  });
console.log(text); // It will print out: "Test punctuation: c, c2, c3, d1. D2. D3. Q?. Ec! Sc; Test number: 1.200 1,200 2.3. Test: money: $15,000. Test double quote and three dots: I said "Today is a... beautiful, sunny day.". But tomorrow will be a long day..."
```

Bonus! I also converted this into Dart as I'm using this feature in Flutter app as well. So just in case someone needs to use it in Dart:

```dart
void main() {
  String addSpaceAfterPunctuation(String words) {
    var regExp = r'\.{3,}$|\s*(?:\d[,.]\d|([,.!?:;]+))(?!\s*$)(?!")\s*';
    
    return words.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(regExp),
      (Match m) {
        return m[1] != null ? "${m[1]} " : "${m[0]}";
      },
    );
  }
  var text = 'Test punctuation:c,c2,c3,d1.D2.D3.Q?.Ec!Sc;Test number:1.200 1,200 2.3.Test:money: \$15,000.Test double quote and three dots:I said "Today is a...beautiful,sunny day.".But tomorrow will be a long day...';
  text = addSpaceAfterPunctuation(text);
  print(text); // Print out: Test punctuation: c, c2, c3, d1. D2. D3. Q?. Ec! Sc; Test number: 1.200 1,200 2.3. Test: money: $15,000. Test double quote and three dots: I said "Today is a... beautiful, sunny day.". But tomorrow will be a long day...
}
```